# Footer does not display properly and hides content at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, navbar, footer

I can't even count how many questions I found about this footer.
So, please, forgive me for this one, as I tried every single answer and yet not able to fix my problem.

Take a webpage with bootstrap's rows and columns.
At the very bottom of it, just before the closing div for the container-fluid, I pasted this code which I later modified to add a second dropdown menu.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar --> 
    <div class="footer navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onClick="history.go(-1)">&#171; MyPage</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="default_theme" class="theme-link">Just black</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="cerulean" class="theme-link">Cerulean</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="cyborg" class="theme-link">Cyborg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="journal" class="theme-link">Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="readable" class="theme-link">Readable</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="simplex" class="theme-link">Simplex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-theme="spacelab" class="theme-link">Spacelab</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-theme="united" class="theme-link">United</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Xml Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="default_xml" class="theme-xml-link">Simple white</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="dark" class="theme-xml-link">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="okaida" class="theme-xml-link">Okaida</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="coy" class="theme-xml-link">Coy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="funky" class="theme-xml-link">Funky</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="solarized-light" class="theme-xml-link">Solarized Light</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" xml-data-theme="twilight" class="theme-xml-link">Twilight</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse --> 
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- closing the container -->

</body>
</html>
```

The code, as it is, works and let me have this navbar placed at the bottom of the page.
I tried replacing `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">` with `<footer class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">` or even `<div class="footer navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">`
And also giving it fixed height on the css.
It just seems that nothing changes.

The last part of my page, gets concealed by this navbar. I can't get to have it "sticky".

Any answer about this issue? I think I read all the questions related to this topic already, but..

**EDIT: Added jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/u2hw5pt2/1/

Comment: Can you provide a working example? (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: @Dekel I'm trying but it is a mess. This one I post is the only html out of the php, the rest is all about if and switch. All working. I checked many times and every tag open and close.
I'm trying exporting or creating to jsfiddle, but it is incredibly hard to reproduce the same problem.. still, i'm trying

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2hw5pt2/ not the best.. the "central panel" is generated by php + database.

Comment: try opening your site in the browser, view the source (cmd+u on chrome/mac) select it all (cmd + a), copy it and paste it in the w3c validator, in that way you can be sure that you didn't forgot to close a tag:
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @Dekel updated with lots of Lorep Ipsum. You may now see that the navbar hides part of the text

Comment: Checked, no errors, just some (many) warning about naming convention etc

Comment: Why don't you just add a little bit of padding to the bottom? https://jsfiddle.net/u2hw5pt2/1/

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see differences, I mean, still the last sentence of lorem ipsum is covered by the navbar

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update the fiddle; here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/u2hw5pt2/2/

Comment: Oh man that is some serious black magic! :D Write this as your answer, I'll upvote and select this one.
Damn. It was so simple

Comment: I think the most important thing you learned is that when you give a complete example you get help pretty fast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sticky footer works by setting it's `position` to `fixed`, which takes it out of the document flow, meaning that for the browser it will not come "after" the content, it will just end up being over it. To avoid this you could just add some padding to the bottom of the body, in order to push the footer a little bit further down:

https://jsfiddle.net/u2hw5pt2/2/

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see your profile pic before, yeah that was me some minutes ago! Thanks mate!